# I wrote a script to clamp my camera and keep it within certain boundaries, but it occasionally shoots up

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, camera

This code perfectly follows my player and keeps the camera within the boundaries to the left, but once the player passes -1.29 on the x-axis the camera starts moving up as the player moves right until it connects with the top boundary in which case it simply stays up there until the player starts moving left again.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class cameraFollower : MonoBehaviour
{
[SerializeField]
GameObject player;

[SerializeField]
float timeOffset;

[SerializeField]
Vector2 posOffset;

[SerializeField]
float leftLimit;
[SerializeField]
float rightLimit;
[SerializeField]
float topLimit;
[SerializeField]
float bottomLimit;

private Vector3 velocity;

void FixedUpdate()
{
    //cam start and end
    Vector3 startPos = transform.position;
    Vector3 endPos = player.transform.position;
    
    //current position of player
    endPos.x += posOffset.x;
    endPos.y += posOffset.y;
    endPos.z += -1;

    transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(startPos, endPos, timeOffset * Time.deltaTime);
    //possible alternate code://transform.position = Vector3.SmoothDamp(startPos, endPos, ref velocity, timeOffset * Time.deltaTime);
    
    transform.position = new Vector3//keep camera within bounds
    (
        Mathf.Clamp(transform.position.x, leftLimit, rightLimit),
        Mathf.Clamp(transform.position.x, bottomLimit, topLimit),
        transform.position.z
    );


}
void OnDrawGizmos()//for use in editor
{
    Gizmos.color = Color.red;
    Gizmos.DrawLine(new Vector2(leftLimit, topLimit), new Vector2(rightLimit, topLimit));//top
    Gizmos.DrawLine(new Vector2(rightLimit, topLimit), new Vector2(rightLimit, bottomLimit));//right
    Gizmos.DrawLine(new Vector2(leftLimit, topLimit), new Vector2(leftLimit, bottomLimit));//left
    Gizmos.DrawLine(new Vector2(leftLimit, bottomLimit), new Vector2(rightLimit, bottomLimit));//bottom
}
}
```

if it helps this is my player movement script which works as intended:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class player_move : MonoBehaviour
{
public float speed;
public float jumpForce;
private float moveInput;
public float checkRadius;
private int extraJumps;
public int extraJumpsValue;
private bool facingRight = true;
private bool isGrounded = true;
public Transform groundCheck;
public LayerMask whatIsGround;
private Rigidbody2D rb;

void Start()
{
    rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();

}

void FixedUpdate()
{
    isGrounded = Physics2D.OverlapCircle(groundCheck.position, checkRadius, whatIsGround);
    
    moveInput = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
    rb.velocity = new Vector2(moveInput * speed * Time.deltaTime, rb.velocity.y);

    if(facingRight == false && moveInput > 0)
    {
        Flip();
    }
    else if(facingRight == true && moveInput < 0)
    {
        Flip();
    }
}
void Flip()
{
    facingRight = !facingRight;
    Vector3 Scaler = transform.localScale;
    Scaler.x *= -1;
    transform.localScale = Scaler;
}
void Update()
{
    if(isGrounded == true)
    {
        extraJumps = extraJumpsValue;
    }
    if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space) && extraJumps > 0)
    {
        rb.velocity = Vector2.up * jumpForce;
        extraJumps--;
    }else if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space) && extraJumps == 0 && isGrounded == true)
    {
        rb.velocity = Vector2.up * jumpForce;
    }
}
}
```